# What to do with floor drains in basement?

Tags: plumbing, basement, floor, drain, remodeling

I'm looking to finish my basement, the house was built in 2005. There is a storage area (it will remain unfinished) with the water heater, hvac, sump pump and storage. There are two floor drains, that are in the family area that I plan on carpeting or tiling.

Should I have the drains relocated to the storage area, covered, or something else?

The house has never had a problem with floods or odors (yet).
Any ideas or steps to take?
Thanks, Jake

Comment: What are the drains for?

Comment: @feetwet The drains let standing water in the basement into the main sewer line.  The drains are also connected to the sump pit, so the water can go there and be pumped out by the sump pump if the main sewer is backed up.

Answer (score 1):

I would stain the concrete or tile it and leave the drains there. I don't think carpet belongs in basements. You are just asking for trouble like mold, mildew, etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Any floor drains should go to plumbing buried under the floor.  You can't just relocate them without a lot of destruction.  If they exist, they were put there for a reason.  You generally don't want to simply remove or cover them.

If you want a more finished look than simply painting the floor, you can put down sheet vinyl or stick-on vinyl tiles.  Vinyl is easy to cut to work around obstacles or to leave openings for floor drains.

If you want something more upscale and have a few inches of ceiling height to spare, you can put in a raised flooring system.  These are often used in offices or computer rooms to simplify running wires.  They consist of a grid framework on feet.  Flooring panels drop into the grid and lift out for access.  This facilitates inspection later for problems, and provides access to the floor for any needed work.  It also protects things from a wet floor (unless you have water several inches deep).